# What will happen if I do not set the window for flink streaming?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-flink

What will happen if I write code like below and do not set time window for flink kafka streaming? What will the print interval be like ?

```html
stream.filter(new FilterFunction<SuperLog>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter(SuperLog superLog) throws Exception {
     return superLog.getDbtbkey().equals("aaaaa") &&
       superLog.getApp_id().equals(1L) &&
       superLog.getRule_id().equals(40048L);
    }
   }).map(new MapFunction<SuperLog, String>() {
    @Override
    public String map(SuperLog superLog) throws Exception {
     return superLog.getSip();
    }
   }).print();
```

Answer (score 0):

The sink(PrintSink) will print the record immediatly when receiving a new record without any delay.